# What's the *right* way to apply a patch from another branch?

Tags: git

I make a fix in one branch and want to apply it to another branch.  Here's what I have been doing:

```
git diff 68610d^ 68610d | git apply
git commit -a -m "SV-656  IP blocking not working  (applying patch from 68610d)"
```

works perfectly but it occurs to me, it doesn't seem like a very git-like way to do things.  In particular, what I am actually doing is only apparent from the comment.  This is a very basic activity and I don't think git would have missed it.

**EDIT**:  is this the function of "cherry-pick"?

Comment: This is exactly what `git cherry-pick` is meant for: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way would be

```
git cherry-pick 68610d
```

If your really wanted to alter the commit message:

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit 68610d
git commit -m "SV-656  IP blocking not working  (applying patch from 68610d)"
```

Comment: You can of course also change the message by cherry-picking then amending! (Saves you having to think ahead.)

Comment: @Jefromi: Indeed. But that results in garbage (as in unreachable commits) clutters the reflog. Besides, it would hardly be specific to this question anymore. +1 your comment as a good _comment_ nevertheless